# Getting error during call webservices methods using jquery

Tags: jquery, .net

Getting error during call web service method using java script.

I want to insert data using web service & java-script. Please help

```
<script src="../js/jquery-1.9.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    function displayMessageCall() {
        //alert("asd");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "http://domain.com.com/demo.asmx/InsertData",
              data: "{ sUserName: 'Aidy', sEmailId: 'F' }",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data.d);

            },

            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert(textStatus);
            }
        });
    }

    function successMsg(response) {
        alert('Success');
    }

    function errorMsg(response) {
        alert(response.status + " " + response.statusText)
    }


</script>
```

I have use fallowing code to call web services methods

```
 [WebMethod]
public static string InsertData(string sUserName, string sEmailId)
{

    string sResult = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        sResult = ExecuteScalar("INSERT INTO vg_demo(UserName, EmailId)VALUES('" + sUserName + "','" + sEmailId + "')").ToString();
    }
    catch
    {
        sResult = "101";
    }
    return sResult;
}

public static string ExecuteScalar(string sQuery)
{

    string sValue = string.Empty;
    SqlCommand oCommand;
    try
    {
        SqlConnection oConnection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MySite"].ConnectionString);
        oCommand = new SqlCommand(sQuery, oConnection);
        oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        using (oConnection)
        {
            oConnection.Open();
            sValue = Convert.ToString(oCommand.ExecuteScalar());
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ApplicationError.LogErrors(ex);
    }

    return sValue;
}
```

I am getting 0 error from errermsg function

Comment: your question is not clear and add few more points.

Comment: I am getting 0 error from errorMsg method

Comment: yeah your question is not defining what error you are getting and more point can you please post your demo webservice url

Comment: Can you remove `contentType` and try again and mention what error you get then? Also, it seems you can do away with `successMsg` and `errorMsg` functions.

Comment: i have removed but still not working. same error